# gnuplot - set mouse mouseformat custom format

Tags: gnuplot

Documentation of `set mouse` [command](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node201.html) shows following formats that can affect the behavior of mouse, in this case the usage of correct format for displaying mouse pointer coordinates, in left bottom corner:

```
0   real coordinates in  brackets e.g. [1.23, 2.45]
1   real coordinates w/o brackets e.g.  1.23, 2.45
2   x == timefmt                       [(as set by `set timefmt`), 2.45]
3   x == date                          [31. 12. 1999, 2.45]
4   x == time                          [23:59, 2.45]
5   x == date / time                   [31. 12. 1999 23:59, 2.45]
6   alt. format, specified as string   ""
```

But following two attempts to set custom format ends up with error `line 0: wrong option`:

```
gnuplot -p -e 'set datafile separator ",";
            set xdata time;
            set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M";
            set format x "%d/%H:%M";
            set mouse mouseformat "mouse = %y/%m/%d %H:%M";
            set autoscale xfix;
            plot "rec-center-hourly.csv" using 1:2 every ::3::616 with lines'

gnuplot -p -e 'set datafile separator ",";
            set xdata time;
            set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M";
            set format x "%d/%H:%M";
            set mouse mouseformat "%y/%m/%d %H:%M";
            set autoscale xfix;
            plot "rec-center-hourly.csv" using 1:2 every ::3::616 with lines'
```

I've aslo tried run it from interactive interpreter:

```
└──> gnuplot -p
Terminal type set to 'wxt'
gnuplot> set datafile separator ",";
gnuplot> set xdata time;
gnuplot> set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M";
gnuplot> set format x "%d/%H:%M";
gnuplot> set mouse mouseformat "mouse = %y/%m/%d %H:%M";
gnuplot> set autoscale xfix;
gnuplot> plot "rec-center-hourly.csv" using 1:2 every ::3::616 with lines

└──> gnuplot -p
gnuplot> set datafile separator ",";
gnuplot> set xdata time;
gnuplot> set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M";
gnuplot> set format x "%d/%H:%M";
gnuplot> set mouse mouseformat "%y/%m/%d %H:%M";
gnuplot> set autoscale xfix;
gnuplot> plot "rec-center-hourly.csv" using 1:2 every ::3::616 with lines
```

Then graph is shown but in left bottom corner is: `mouse = %y/Argument list too long/7827416 %H:M` instead of coordinates.

I've also noticed another strange behavior, here is excerpt from mentioned page again:

```
1   real coordinates w/o brackets e.g.  1.23, 2.45
2   x == timefmt                       [(as set by `set timefmt`), 2.45]
3   x == date                          [31. 12. 1999, 2.45]
```

Seems like the numbers for `set mouse mouseformat X` command is shifted for some reason:

In my machine following sets `timefmt` and not `date`

```
gnuplot -p -e 'set datafile separator ",";
            set xdata time;
            set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M";
            set format x "%d/%H:%M";
            set mouse mouseformat 3;
            set autoscale xfix;
            plot "rec-center-hourly.csv" using 1:2 every ::3::616 with lines'
```

and following sets `real coordinates w/o brackets e.g.  1.23, 2.45` and not `timefmt`

```
gnuplot -p -e 'set datafile separator ",";
            set xdata time;
            set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M";
            set format x "%d/%H:%M";
            set mouse mouseformat 2;
            set autoscale xfix;
            plot "rec-center-hourly.csv" using 1:2 every ::3::616 with lines'
```

Comment: Several things: To change the value displayed in left bottom corner, use `set mouse format`, `set mouse mouseformat` changes the appearance of the label displayed when you click somewhere. Next, the doc says, that this format is given to `sprintf`, which doesn't understand time formats, and requires two formatting specifiers only, for `x` and `y`. Concerning the shift: In the 4.6 docs it says, that `3` gives you `timefmt`. Note, that the doc you linked at is from 4.2!

Comment: Hello Christoph, So there is no way to have left bottom corner in `""%y/%m/%d %H:%M"` format?

Comment: I'm afraid, no. Have you tried using `set mouse format 1`?` This should give you the same format as given to the axes. Maybe that's an option.

Comment: It gives me `wrong option`

Comment: As of gnuplot 6, the "set mouse format" command has been superseded by "set mouse mouseformat", the former being a subset of the latter.

Answer (score 2):

According to v5.0 doc, the predefined formats are for `mouseformat`:

```
Use set mouse mouseformat "" to turn this string off again.
The following formats are available:
0 default (same as 1)
1 axis coordinates 1.23, 2.45
2 graph coordinates (from 0 to 1) /0.00, 1.00/
3 x = timefmt y = axis [(as set by ‘set timefmt‘), 2.45]
4 x = date y = axis [31. 12. 1999, 2.45]
5 x = time y = axis [23:59, 2.45]
6 x = date time y = axis [31. 12. 1999 23:59, 2.45]
7 format from ‘set mouse mouseformat‘, e.g. "mouse x,y = 1.23, 2.450"
```

I've put an example using:

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
set mouse mouseformat 3
```

[image]

If I try it with `set mouse format 3` I also get the `wrong option` error.